# Young diagram as float in tufte-book

Tags: floats, equations, tufte

I am trying to place Young diagrams (using youngtab) in the margin, as in the tufte-book document class.

I have tried the obvious

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
 $\young(\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil)$
  \caption{Diagram of shape $(5,4,2,2)$}\label{fig:diagramExample}
\end{figure}
```

But this does not work; the diagram is centred in the middle, and not at the side.
I also get the error message "figure with no caption on input line xx".

If I use say amsart document class, then everything works as expected.

So, what is the solution to this problem? I would appreciate a solution which makes it easy to switch back to amsart if I would like to.

EDIT:

So this is part of my preable:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,sfsidenotes,numbers]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym,enumerate,youngtab}
\usepackage{epigraph,graphicx}
```

The result I get is as below, but I want the diagram to appear on the left hand side, like a normal pictures
[image: A picture describing my output]

Minimal example

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[sfsidenotes,numbers]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym,enumerate,youngtab}
\usepackage{epigraph,graphicx}

\title{Minimal}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}
   \centering
    $ e^x $
  \caption{Caption here}\label{fig:skewDiagramExample}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine for me. can you add some more info?

Comment: I realized that what I want is "marginfigure". But I still get the "figure with no caption" warning.

Comment: Hm, no, the warnings disappeared. But, with ordinary "figure" environmen, I get the warning. Can I get rid of that?

Comment: I get no such warnings in either case.  Can you post a complete minimal document.

Comment: Ok, @AndrewSwann, I have added a minimal example.

Comment: The warning is coming from the `nag` package.  It doesn't know the internals of all documentclass or packages and so often can produce spurious messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put figures in the margin, one uses `marginfigure` instead of `figure`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[sfsidenotes,numbers]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{youngtab}

\usepackage{lipsum} %For dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
 $\young(\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil)$
  \caption{Diagram of shape $(5,4,2,2)$}\label{fig:diagramExample}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
 $\young(\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil)$
  \caption{Diagram of shape $(5,4,2,2)$}\label{fig:diagramExample2}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

There is nothing specific to Yound diagrams in this.
The only warning the above code produces in the log file is related to the `bibentry` package, and not to any of the figures.  On the other hand adding

\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

writes

> Package nag Warning: figure with no \caption on input line 15.

in the `.log` file.  The `nag` package doesn't know about the `tufte` documentclasses, which redefines the `figure` environment to put the caption in the margin.  As the `nag` documentation says

> Be warned, that this package will possibly balk at legitimate use, and
>   not find illegitimate use in all cases. It is a tool, not a
>   replacement for study of l2tabu.

However, you can teach `nag` to deal correctly with your situation by making it recognise `\@tufte@caption` as a caption command:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[sfsidenotes,numbers]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{youngtab}

\usepackage{lipsum} %For dummy text

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\nag@captions{,@tufte@caption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
 $\young(\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil)$
  \caption{Diagram of shape $(5,4,2,2)$}\label{fig:diagramExample}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
 $\young(\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil,\hfil\hfil)$
  \caption{Diagram of shape $(5,4,2,2)$}\label{fig:diagramExample2}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```